# GridView selector overlapping

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a card style `GridView` like Google Music app.

To accomplish this, I create the following selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/card_grid_bg_pressed">
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/card_grid_bg_normal">
    </item>
</selector>
```

The first drawable is [image: card_grid_bg_pressed] and the second one is [image: card_grid_bg_hover].

It's working but the problem is that I couldn't achieve my desired behavior; because when you pressed Google Music `GridView` item's, the pressed selector will overlap the normal item.

Here is a screenshot of what I want:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do such a thing, I used a simple drawable, and used the `setForeground` method on my view.
The drawable I used was part of the ActionBarSherlock library (I'll let you find it abs__list_focused_holo.9.png).

So, in my custom adapter, I had a method named setItemChecked(int position, int boolean, View v) which used the setForeground to change the ForeGround of the view v.

Note that the view was a FrameLayout, since as far as I know these or the only views with this method.

```
public void setItemChecked(int position, boolean checked, View v) {
        if(checked) {
            if(v!=null)
                ((FrameLayout) v).setForeground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abs__list_focused_holo));
            else
                Log.w(LOGCAT_TAG, "v is null. Can't change foreground");
        }
        else {
            if(v!=null)
                ((FrameLayout) v).setForeground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent));
            else
                Log.w(LOGCAT_TAG, "v is null. Can't change foreground");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I like to change it through my current selector, not from code.

Comment: Well, are you using your selector as a background ? Maybe you could use it as a Foreground instead, because the background would be behind the view, while the foreground should be in top of it.

Comment: Well, your custom item view need to be a FrameLayout, I think this is the only view that can use the ForeGround property, and assign it this drawable. But, I'm not sure this work. If it doesn't, I'd say doing it programmatically like this could be the only way to do so!